# Setting/Override x-frame-option for only for a specific page on Magento 2.1

Tags: magento, iframe, http-headers, magento2, x-frame-options

Magento 2.1 set X-Frame-Option header for all frontend pages as SAMEORIGIN. it allow us to change it on app/etc/env.php configuration but it will change for all pages on the frontend.

On my case I want to change it for a specific page. Setting this on the controller doesn't work because Magento overrides it later in a Plugin call.

I've managed to achieve this using Plugin the same way Varnish Module sets its headers.

But, since I want to allow it for just one page I am not happy with this approach since it is adding some overhead on every response on frontend. It may be the proper Magento way of doing it but I am new with Magento so I am not sure.

I am not doing much on there which will not have a huge impact on the requests since I am not using DB or anything for the other pages. but I would like to know if someone has found a better approach for that.

```
<?php
namespace Nei\MyModule\Plugin;
use Nei\MyModule\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\NotCacheableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;
/**
 * HTTP response plugin for frontend.
 */
class AllowOriginHeaderForTrackingPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $config;
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;
    public function __construct(
        Config $config,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    /**
     * Magento by default override X-Frame-Option header after Dispatcher.
     * So setting this header on controller will be overridden
     *
     * With this Plugin we override Magento's override for X-Frame-Option
     *
     * @param Http $subject
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeSendResponse(Http $subject)
    {
        if ($subject instanceof NotCacheableInterface) {
            return;
        }
        // Only for tracking action
        $frontName = strtolower($this->request->getFrontName());
        $actionName = strtolower($this->request->getActionName());

        // @TODO: update the frontend and action name here
        if ($frontName === 'something' && $actionName === 'anything') {
            $xFrameOption = $this->config->getXFrameOption();
            if (!empty($xFrameOption) && $this->config->isTrackingEnabled()) {
                $subject->setXFrameOptions('ALLOW-FROM '.$xFrameOption);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I register my Plugin using di.yml

```
<!-- Nei_MyModule/etc/frontend/di.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http">
        <plugin name="nei-mymodule-allow-origin" type="Nei\MyModule\Plugin\AllowOriginHeaderForTrackingPlugin"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you find any other approaches since we're looking to override the header for a specific page only in Magento 2.2.x site?